# React native tab navigation - tab change blocked until fetch is complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native tab navigation (with material tabs).Inside that tab navigation there are 2 tabs that both do initial data fetch when the tab is activated only once(the first render) and when the data page is changed(infinite scroll).

When first tab is activated and data fetching is in progress, I can't switch to second tab until fetch is over.When i click on the second tab nothing happens but the click is somehow registered, and tab is switched with a delay as soon as the fetch on the previous tab is completed.

My question is, can this tab change be ublocked when fetching data in one of the tabs is in progress.

Here's the code

Initial fetch, the same effect is applied when user scrolls to the bottom to load new data(infinite scroll)

```
  useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({ name: 'spinner' });
        fetch(route.params.apiUrl + items.page).then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error('Nije OK Status')
            }
            return res
        }).then((promise) => promise.json()).then((data) => {
            dispatch({ name: 'load', data: data })
        })
    }, [items.page])
```

function that increments page number, that triggers loading new data

```
const loadMore = () => {
        dispatch({ name: 'page increment' })
    }
```

FlatList

```
 <>
            {items.isLoading ? <View style={styles.indicator}><ActivityIndicator size="large" color={constants.secondary} /></View> : null}
            <FlatList numColumns={1}
                onEndReached={loadMore}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                initialNumToRender={10}
                maxToRenderPerBatch={30}
                data={items.data}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                removeClippedSubviews={true}
                ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
            />
        </>
```

Comment: Have you managed to fix this, Im having the same problem

Comment: Having the same issue in 2023 and no solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loading state while fetch is working and disable tab while loading is true (there must be 'disabled' property for Tab component).

Comment: It can be done like that, but I would like for user to be able to switch tabs at any point.Either cancel ongoing data fetch in the previous tab, or fetch to continue in the background since these tabs screens do not unmount.